# Unable to export time series from MODIS NDVI in GEE as transforming geometry into requested projection not working

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, remote-sensing, time-series

I am trying to acquire MODIS NDVI (MOD13Q1 v061) time series using Google Earth Engine for certain locations for which I have the coordinates. My code looks as follows:

```
////////// Input

// Specify dataset
var dataset = 'MODIS/061/MOD13Q1';

// Specify variable name
var variable = 'NDVI';

// Specify scale factor
var scale = 0.0001;

// Specify the date range of interest
var startDate = '2010-01-01';
var endDate = '2022-12-31';

// Specify a list of sites with names and coordinates
var sites = [
  {'name': 'AAC001', 'lat': 59.664, 'lon': 10.762},
  {'name': 'WUC002', 'lat': 50.505, 'lon': 6.331}
];

////////// Processing

// Load the image collection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(dataset)
                 .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                 .select(variable);

// Define projection of the image collection
var projection = collection.first().projection();

// Loop over the sites and export the time series as a CSV file for each site
sites.forEach(function(site) {
  
  // Create a point geometry from the coordinates
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(site.lon, site.lat).transform(projection);

  // Filter the image collection based on the point geometry
  var collectionPoint = collection.filterBounds(point);

  // Get the value for point for each image in the collection
  var timeseries = collectionPoint.map(function(image) {
    var mean = image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: point,
      scale: scale,
      crs: projection,
      maxPixels: 1e9,
    });
    return image.set(variable, mean.get(variable));
  });

  // Export the time series as a CSV file
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: timeseries,
    description: dataset.replace(/\//g, '_') + '_' + variable + '_' + site.name,
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
  });
});
```

However, I get the following error:

Error: Error in map(ID=2010_02_18): Image.reduceRegion: Unable to transform geometry into requested projection. (Error code: 3)

- I tried out a different projection (EPSG:4326), but this gives the same error.
- I tried out shortening the temporal frame, as the product is available from 2000-02-18 to 2023-06-10, but this gives the same error.
- I tried out adding a buffer around the points, but this gives the same error.
- I tried out avoiding the reprojection, but this gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerous issues:

1. "scale" always means meters in Earth Engine. You've specified a scale of 0.0001 meters. That's probably not what you meant, and it exceeds the geometry precision available.  Use something meaningful.
2. ee.Geometry.Point takes a list of coordinates, you've specified them as separate arguments.
3. There's absolutely no reason to call `transform()` on the point.  Just leave it off.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/512e7d348fb576800a83833419a2e50a

Comment: Many thanks! It seems like the low scale caused the issue. Now I can export the time series. The low scale of 0.0001 I got from the Data Catalog: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MOD13Q1. However, this refers to scale the NDVI values.